# JQuery + Find Checkbox with ; in id

Tags: jquery

I am currently using Jquery to alter a 3rd party product and ran across this particular limitation...I think

Currently the checkbox ID and Name value have a ; in it see below

```
<input id="K48_h6;547ECE8D417501D623E11F94E0DF94FD" name="K48_1" value="h6;547ECE8D417501D623E11F94E0DF94FD" type="checkbox" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

I am trying to force Jquery to Check this box.  This is the Jquery I have right now.

```
$("#K48_h6;547ECE8D417501D623E11F94E0DF94FD").prop("checked",true);
```

This is causing me to have a Object doesn't support this property or method.

Since this is a 3rd party product there is nothing I can do with the ;,  The Jquery run post the server side code loading.

Comment: `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html According to this, you've an invalid ID

Comment: of course you are aware than having ';' in ID attribute is not valid. Cannot you replace it?

Comment: @Ejay in HTML5, IDs starting with number are valid now

Comment: @roasted thanks for adding useful information to the page :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to escaping, which is a fine solution, it seems this limitation doesn't exist when filtering for `id` as an attribute, like this:

```
$("input[id='K48_h6;547ECE8D417501D623E11F94E0DF94FD']").prop("checked",true);
```

See [**working demo**](http://tinker.io/9612c)

Answer (score 1):

Use native JS with `document.getElementById()` rather than just jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/droppedonjapan/ppFSh/1/

## EDIT

If you need to have that element wrapped in jQuery, you can wrap it after capturing the element with getElementById().

Comment: +1 - it's good to always keep in mind that you're writing *JavaScript*, using the jQuery library, rather than a mysterious language called "jQuery".

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just escaping (note the `\\` before the `;`) the invalid characters:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('#K48_h6\\;547ECE8D417501D623E11F94E0DF94FD').prop('checked',true);
})
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ppFSh/2/).

Note that I don't particularly recommend trying to work around the use of invalid characters in your `id`s, I would *seriously* and quite strongly recommend changing whatever 3rd-party product you're using, for one that's capable of generating *valid* `id` properties/attributes.

Comment: This will only work if you are manually entering the ID you're wanting.  If you get that value from the DOM somewhere, you can get it to work doing `idVariable.replace(';', '/;')`

Comment: Well, strictly speaking `idVariable.replace(/;/g,'\\\\;')`, surely? And if replacing is happening, then it'd be far easier to just *remove* the `;` characters, rather than escaping them.

Comment: Haha yeah derp.  That'll be the last time I whip out `.replace()` code off the top of my head.  :P